# Azure blob storage access - no exceptions but no write

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage

I'm attempting to store a file in Azure Blob storage - I get no exceptions but the file does not appear. I am obviously doing something wrong. I have a basic test as follows:

```
            CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse("DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=mystorage1;AccountKey=1xxxxxusCw==");
            CloudBlobClient blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
            CloudBlobContainer container = blobClient.GetContainerReference("myimagecontainer");
            CloudBlockBlob blob = container.GetBlockBlobReference($"image.jpg");

            using (var fileStream = System.IO.File.OpenRead(@"C:\temp\image.jpg"))
            {
                blob.UploadFromStreamAsync(fileStream);
            }
```

Access Type is 'Blob'.

Any ideas why this would not work (obviously I have changed the account info etc)?

Thanks

Comment: Does the container exist?  Also you might want to try using the non-async version "UploadFromStream" first to get it working.  Then add the async.

Comment: Yes the container exists. Non-async UploadFromStream not supported in DNX Core 5.0. I'm using .NET Core so referencing Windows.Azure.Storage 7.0.1-preview, which may be an issue although something as basic as this I doubt that. I should test with 4.6 I guess.

Comment: I haven't touch Core yet. Only other possibility is that the possible error is not being handled because of the async.  Try awaiting the upload and/or double check how exceptions are being handled.

Comment: @StephenMcDowell thanks! It was just that I was not awaiting. All good now. Add as an Answer and I'll accept it, if you wish.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The possible error is not being handled because of the async. Try awaiting the upload and/or double check how exceptions are being handled.